# Using rails draper gem with angularjs and json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, draper

so, I have seen people dancing around this topic, but I can't find the answer.  I just installed the 'draper' gem with rails.  It's great, but I want to be able to use it with angularjs.  Is there a way to do that?  Or do I need to just make a costum decorator in angularjs.... which would mean my 'draper' gem is useless:

```
class PageDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all


 def emphatic
   object.text.upcase
 end

end
```

and my html is:

```
<li class="gregli" ng-repeat="page in pages">
  {{ page.text }}
</li>
```

and my rails controller is:

```
def index
    @pages = Page.all.decorate
    render json: @pages
end
```